# Can't start docker on Ubuntu 14.04: Job failed to start

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vagrant

I'm trying to installed Docker on a Vagrantbox with Ubuntu 14.04 using the instructions on the official website ([Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/)). The installation seemed to work, but afterwards I can't start the docker service using `sudo service docker start` it gives me the following error message:

`start: Job failed to start`

If I try `docker ps -a` then I get the following error message:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

Kernel: Linux vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Relevant lines from /var/log/upstart/docker.log

`Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock`
`Invalid value "" for flag --mtu: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "": invalid syntax`

Comment: Check the actual logs for docker, likely at `/var/log/upstart/docker.log`. Update your question if there are other relevant lines

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by @brent the solution was looking into the logs at `/var/log/upstart/docker.log`, which showed that the --mtu parameter was empty. In  my case it was dependent on a environment variable that wasn't set.

Comment: Great, glad you sorted it

Comment: and where did you fix the missing parameter?